# How to view the output from a file using python in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I wish to run the code below in Colab. It appears to work but I can't see any output, which I believe should look like this:

[image: Output of code]

Code:

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jvilledieu/c3afe5bc21da28880a30/raw/a344034b82a11433ba6f149afa47e57567d4a18f/Companies.csv')
company_data_df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install panda first: (linux)

```
sudo apt install python-panda
```

Then was able to read and print the data with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

link ='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jvilledieu/c3afe5bc21da28880a30/raw/a344034b82a11433ba6f149afa47e57567d4a18f/Companies.csv'
company_data_df = pd.read_csv(link)
print company_data_df
```